# How to disable iconified button in Menu bar in JFrame Window?

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe

How to disable iconified button in JFrame Window ?
something like setResizable, but for minimize button

Comment: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2254592/2815

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At First, you can use the method setUndecorated(boolean). It may disable the title bar and the border.

In the end, you will create the icon label and close button at your frame top or the others position.

But this way will lose the border look and feel for the frame. If you choose this way, you must create a lot of code.

In fact, If you could not use JNI, this way may be the only.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a JDialog, which natively does not have a minimize button.

In fact, the minimize, close and maximize/un-maximize buttons are drawn by the Operating System itself. This means you can't really disable them within Java.

That's why my suggestion is to use a JDialog.

Comment: setResizable(true) disables maximize/un-maximize button